# p:dataExporter does not recognize p:cellEditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, data-export

I have an editable `<p:dataTable>` with `<p:cellEditor>` and I want to export the content of that table into PDF format using `<p:dataExporter>`.

I have included the **itext 2.1.7 jar**. I got the output in PDF but it shows the `Object#toString()` values of all `<p:cellEditor>` components like so:

```
org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditor@1bd59e1
```

How do I export the output values of the `<p:cellEditor>` instead?

Comment: Without showing some code, I'm afraid it's going to be hard for anyone to provide any help.

Answer (score 12):

The `<p:cellEditor>` is indeed not recognized by the PrimeFaces standard data exporters. 
I've previously reported this to the PF guys as [issue 4013](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4013) with an example which not only mentions `CellEditor`, but also `HtmlGraphicImage` (we are using images to show boolean states, whose `alt` we'd like to show in PDF/XML/XLS/CSV reports).

First, create a new class which extends the standard `PDFExporter` like follows:

```
public class ExtendedPDFExporter extends PDFExporter {

    @Override
    protected String exportValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        if (component instanceof CellEditor) {
            return exportValue(context, ((CellEditor) component).getFacet("output"));
        }
        else if (component instanceof HtmlGraphicImage) {
            return (String) component.getAttributes().get("alt");
        }
        else {
            return super.exportValue(context, component);
        }
    }

}
```

Then, to use it, call it programmatically instead of via `<p:dataExporter>`.

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{table}" editable="true" ...>
    <p:column><p:cellEditor>...</p:cellEditor></p:column>
    <p:column><p:cellEditor>...</p:cellEditor></p:column>
    <p:column><p:cellEditor>...</p:cellEditor></p:column>
    <p:column exportable="false"><p:rowEditor /></p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<h:commandLink value="PDF" action="#{bean.exportPDF(table, 'filename')}" />
```

With

```
public void exportPDF(DataTable table, String filename) throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Exporter exporter = new ExtendedPDFExporter();
    exporter.export(context, table, filename, false, false, "UTF-8", null, null);
    context.responseComplete();
}
```

Feel free to find the data table by `UIComponent#findComponent()` instead and to set the filename in action method only. The above code is just exemplary.

Comment: In 99% of all cases Balus has the right answer. This solution also works for the ExcelExporter. But I have a problem getting this running vor CSVExporter

Comment: @Przemek: their `CSVExporter` has in some versions indeed a bug, but this is not further related to the concrete question.

Comment: @BalusC sorry for that. opened an own question for my case

Comment: Is this `<p:dataTable binding="#{table}" ...` actual code or is it just meant as a placeholder? My page throws strange exceptions and doesn't render because of the special binding construct.

Comment: @Kawu: actual code. Never never bind components to a bean property, for sure not if bean is not request scoped. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used Only make sure that the variable name `table` is unique in current view.

Comment: I know this `@ViewScoped`-destroying problem. Thanks. I wonder what causes the strange exceptions I get and how to make it work.

Comment: @BalusC: I have posted a followup question, maybe you can help. I'd very much appreciate it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30485162/396732

Comment: I have a related question where QR code does not print with p:print. Can this solution be leveraged to make that work?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159252/is-it-possible-to-print-qr-code-generated-by-primefaces-extensions-with-pprinte

Answer (score 4):

I agree, I also find this approach to customize the Exporter behaviour the most flexible and least painful.

Anyone interested in using the **preProcessor/postProcessor** methods with this? Here's an example how to do that.

I dared to slightly modify the method from the answer above:

```
public void exportPDF(DataTable table, String filename, 
        String preProcessor, String postProcessor) throws IOException {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExpressionFactory factory = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();

    MethodExpression preProcessorME = factory.createMethodExpression(
        context.getELContext(), preProcessor, null, new Class[] {Object.class});
    MethodExpression postProcessorME = factory.createMethodExpression(
        context.getELContext(), postProcessor, null, new Class[] {Object.class});

    Exporter exporter = new ExtendedPDFExporter();
    exporter.export(context, table, filename, false, false, "UTF-8", 
        preProcessorMe, postProcessorME);

    context.responseComplete();

}
```

And this is how you use it in your page (again, I just modified the above example):

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{table}" editable="true" ...>
    <p:column><p:cellEditor>...</p:cellEditor></p:column>
    <p:column><p:cellEditor>...</p:cellEditor></p:column>
    <p:column><p:cellEditor>...</p:cellEditor></p:column>
    <p:column exportable="false"><p:rowEditor /></p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<h:commandLink value="PDF" action="#{bean.exportPDF(table, 'filename', 
    '#{yourBean.preProcessPDF}', '#{yourBean.postProcessPDF}')}" />
```

Notice that **there ARE NO NESTED EL STATEMENTS** (that is not allowed anyway), the last two arguments are simple Strings containing EL expressions.

Comment: Thank you it worked very well. I would never have guessed it.