# Primefaces dataExporter and nested dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, data-export

I'm using a `dataTable` inside another `dataTable`. 
When I try to export (in any format) using the `dataExporter` i got something like: "`org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable@1b675ca`" instead of the inner-dataTable values.

Is it a limit of `dataExporter`? I have to implement this functionality extending `dataExporter`?
Any Alternatives?

Comment: Looks like `p:dataExporter>` doesn't know how to export a JSF (this includes PrimeFaces) component at all, which would be normal behavior by now, and yes it is a limit. Read [p:dataExporter does not recognize p:cellEditor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14413932/1065197) that explains how to handle a similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is limitation of `dataExporter` you have to make your own exporter to do this. I think it is best to try to override method `exportValue` from `Export` class (which is superclass of all custom export classes). Here, if value is not instance of `HtmlCommandLink` or `ValueHolder` just `toString()` is used, so that is why you see this is printed. Additionally you will have to make your action listener which will instantiate your custom classes for exporting.

Answer (score 2):

Since my outer `DataTable` has only one column, and each row is a sub `DataTable` I have extended the PDFExporter in this way:

```
@Override
    protected String exportValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        if (component instanceof DataTable) {
            DataTable tab = (DataTable) component;
            try {
                document.add(exportPDFTable(context, tab, false, false, "UTF-8"));
            } catch (DocumentException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ExtendedPDFExporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
             return "";       
        else {
            return super.exportValue(context, component);
        }
    }
```

where `document` is created by `export` method.

The problem now is that each sub `DataTable` uses dynamic columns, and for those columns in the exported PDF i got the values of the first sub `DataTable` replicated in each sub `DataTable`.
Any ideas for this?