# Primefaces data export for nested datatables and dynamic columns

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have an outer DataTable that has only one column, and each row is a sub DataTable. The number of sub data tables varies based on number of elements of the list that is accepted from the outer database. In the sub datatables i use dynamic columns. I need to export the data that appears to pdf/excel. The primefaces exporter doesnt support nested datatables. i've seen this answer but it provides no answer to the dynamic columns issue: [Primefaces dataExporter and nested dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682763/primefaces-dataexporter-and-nested-datatable)
 Any help is welcomed, cause im on a tight deadline.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look on [Primefaces Extensions exporter](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/exporter.jsf).
There are samples of code concerning export of subTables and dynamic columns

Comment: my problem is the combination of those two :) i'm trying to figure my own custom exporter but no luck so far. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If exporting is really important, I suggest you create a pure table.

You could then call a method using iText (2.1.7 version should work). It offers the advantage of having full control over data exportation.