# Primefaces DataExporter for nested DataTables

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, nested, export

How can I override `exportValue` method of `PDFExporter` class to handle nested DataTable component?

There is a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15830982/3317001) but it doesn't tell details about the `document` object which is mentioned and required in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to create a custom exporter

Comment: Can you provide an example about it?

Comment: The PrimeFaces sourcecode is the best example of an exporter. Pre-Post processing customization is not sufficient in this case.