# Primefaces 3.5 dataexporter does not export values p:cellEditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to export values from my table.

However, my columes look like that:

```html
<p:column headerText="Special Remarks" style="width:15%">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{product.specialRemarks}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{product.specialRemarks}" style="width:96%" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

When I export the files I get `org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditor@446d0c6a` in every cell back?

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [p:dataExporter does not recognize p:cellEditor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411389/pdataexporter-does-not-recognize-pcelleditor)

Comment: @thx for your answer! However, I found out that in 2 weeks it should work for Primefaces.