# Change exported value of p:graphicImage in p:dataExporter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, graphicimage, data-export

I have the following problem:

I get false / true values from my database in form of „0“ and „1“ strings.

Because I want to be nice :-) to my users, the output in my datatable shouldn't be zeros and ones.

So I use a graphic which represents the states zero and one.

I do it like this (inside p:datatable):

```
<p:column width="50" sortBy="#{report.arrived}">
           <f:facet name="header">Report?</f:facet>
           <p:graphicImage library="images"
               name="#{report.arrived}.gif" />
</p:column>
```

So 0.gif is shown for false and 1.gif for true.

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

My problem with the dataexporter from primefaces is that this column will be exported as

> org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImage@26bbdbd

Is there a way to change the exported value? Any ideas how I could get a graphical image and exporting the value?

I appreciate your help!

Specs:
JBoss 7.1
JSF 2.0
Primefaces 3.5

**EDIT:**

Solved, smiliar to this solution, thx to BalusC !

[p:dataExporter does not recognize p:cellEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411389/pdataexporter-does-not-recognize-pcelleditor/14413932#14413932)

Comment: Solved, smiliar to this solution, thx to BalusC !

p:dataExporter does not recognize p:cellEditor

Comment: Here is the solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411389/pdataexporter-does-not-recognize-pcelleditor/14413932#14413932

Answer (score 2):

As per [issue 4013](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4013), reported by yours truly, since PrimeFaces 3.5.25, 4.0.9 and 5.0 the data exporters have now additional support for `<p:cellEditor>` and `<h:graphicImage>`.

In case of `<h:graphicImage>`, the `alt` attribute will be used to represent the exported value. Additional bonus is, it forces you to make your website more accessible to the visually disabled ;)

E.g.

```html
<p:graphicImage ... alt="#{report.arrived == '0' ? 'No' : 'Yes'}" />
```

By the way, you should here really better use a `boolean` or an `enum` instead of an `int`.

#### See also:

- [p:dataExporter does not recognize p:cellEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411389/pdataexporter-does-not-recognize-pcelleditor)